# NextAuth fetch session errors on production (localhost)

Tags: authentication, next.js, next-auth

Im testing my nextauth application.. it works in dev, it builds and when i try to run it as a produciton on my own localhost i get the following error

```
[next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#client_fetch_error fetch failed {
  error: {
    message: 'fetch failed',
    stack: 'TypeError: fetch failed\n' +
      '    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11118:11)\n' +
      '    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)',
    name: 'TypeError'
  },
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/session',
  message: 'fetch failed'
```

The session link is valid, when i click on it it shows, however it not making it to the application and thus the user cant proceed.

Symtoms, the callback from either a social or email (magic links) is failing. Its setting the sesison but fails go beyond.

I tried a few different solutions based on the error such as setting secret etc from other posts but it doesnt work.

At first i was use JWT with callbacks but I disabled all of those to keep things simple. I tried both JWT and Database and its still not working

my code

```
export default NextAuth({

    adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
    // Configure one or more authentication providers
    providers: [
      EmailProvider({
        server: {
          host: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_HOST,
          port: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PORT,
          auth: {
            user: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_USER,
            pass: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PASSWORD
          }
        },
        from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM
      }),

 
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    AppleProvider({
        clientId: process.env.APPLE_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.APPLE_SECRET
    }),
    FacebookProvider({
        clientId: process.env.FACEBOOK_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_SECRET
    }),

  ],
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
   // The secret should be set to a reasonably long random string.
  // It is used to sign cookies and to sign and encrypt JSON Web Tokens, unless
  // a separate secret is defined explicitly for encrypting the JWT.
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
 
  session: {
    strategy: 'database',
  },
```

I have a .env file with the following

NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000

NEXTAUTH_SECRET=4lA346O4535468n73+fbYBO0L1uhAqs=

for the authentication to go through and enable sessions